# can I query mysql databases in nest js without the need for TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm learning NestJS, I'm currently reading about DB queries with TypeORM. However, I want to know if there is the possibility of doing native SQL queries (That is, without using any ORM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, there is. It is even pointed out in [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#database):

```
You can also directly use any general purpose Node.js database integration
library or ORM, such as MikroORM also check the recipe here,
Sequelize (navigate to the Sequelize integration section), Knex.js (tutorial), TypeORM, and Prisma (recipe) , to operate at a higher level of abstraction.
```

So feel free to use any technology you want. Personally I use [kysely](https://github.com/koskimas/kysely) as a query builder